# Check if device supports ScreenOrientation.lock() - Uncaught Error screen.orientation.lock() is not available on this device

Tags: javascript, css, typescript

I'm following the documentation for `ScreenOrientation.lock()` but I can't get it to work as I want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock

When calling `window.screen.orientation.lock("portrait");` on Chrome desktop I get the error `screen.orientation.lock() is not available on this device.` as a Uncaught Error. Is there anyway to check if a device supports locking?

I have already put `"orientation":"portrait"` into `manifest.json` but this is only default orientation and not a lock.

https://www.w3.org/TR/appmanifest/#orientation-member

Side notes:

I had some trouble understanding how to call the method. Example errors if anyone finds this thread:

```
ScreenOrientation.prototype.lock("portrait");

window.ScreenOrientation.prototype.lock("portrait");
```

Leads to this exception:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'lock' on
>   'ScreenOrientation': Illegal invocation

```
(ScreenOrientation as any).lock("portrait");
```

Leads to this exception:

> TypeError: ScreenOrientation.lock is not a function

Comment: A fallback method would be to catch the exception. Doesn’t strictly answer the “detect if” pre-hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`window.screen.orientation.lock()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). A promise will call one of the functions that you provide to a chained `then()` method, depending on whether the promise was resolved (success) or rejected (failure).

You could make your call to `window.screen.orientation.lock()` like this:

```
window.screen.orientation
    .lock("portrait")
    .then(
        success => console.log(success),
        failure => console.log(failure)
    )
```

You will probably want to put something more useful in the `resolve` and `reject` methods, but this will at least catch the rejection and prevent an Unhandled Rejection error from being thrown.

Comment: The suggested code did not work for me : window.screen.orientation.lock('portrait').then(success => window.screen.orientation.lock('portrait'));  Did I misunderstand the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think rotation in mobile requires an event listener to handle `screen.orientation.lock` error. This code works for me

The `.main-app` is a body tag class.

In your HTML code add a button like:

```
    <div id="lock-landscape-btn" class="hidden">Lock</div>
    <div id="unlock-orientation" class="hidden">unLock</div>
```

In your JS code/file add an EventListener like:

```
    function rotateScreen () {

        document.querySelector('#lock-landscape-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {

            if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

                if(document.querySelector(".main-app").requestFullscreen) {
                    document.querySelector(".main-app").requestFullscreen();
                }else if(document.querySelector(".main-app").webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                    document.querySelector(".main-app").webkitRequestFullScreen();
                }

                screen.orientation.lock("landscape-primary")
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('landscape-primary');
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }

        });

        document.querySelector("#unlock-orientation").addEventListener('click', function() {
            screen.orientation.unlock();
        });
    };
```